# questions on reading files in python 3

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
     count = 0
     for i in range(0,1+len(Text)-len(Pattern)):
         if Text[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
             count = count + 1
     return count
Text = input("enter 1st number")
Pattern = input("enter 1st number")
print(PatternCount(Text,Pattern))
```

l want to read file and sort its contents into text and pattern, instead of the user input below:

```
 Text = input("enter 1st number")
 Pattern = input("enter 1st number")
```

How can l do that? 
the file is text file and has two lines: 
one is a long DNA string and the other line is a specific pattern

Comment: What about just redirecting the input file to stdin of the program? `python3 script.py < input`.

Comment: could you please clarify your answer? l tried `with open("") as myfile`

Comment: I just ran your existing code with the command shown and it worked.

Comment: l run this command `python3 PatternCount.py < dataset_2_7.txt` in my command prompt and it give me an empty space. and l use the same code above with deleting these lines `Text = input("enter 1st number")
 Pattern = input("enter 1st number")`. l used the same directory path the files in. so how did it work with you?

Comment: Don't delete the lines.

Answer (score 0):

## To read 2 lines from file instead of user input.

try this code

```
f = open("fileName", "r")
text = f.readline().strip() #Strip is to remove unwanted \n or space at both end
pattern = f.readline().strip()
```

Please read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp) for more on python-file-handling